# file and folder permission settings for WordPress folder on linux

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I have moved my website project to a linux environment and I have an issue assigning permission.

Command that I run:

```
sudo chown -R admin01:admin01 /var/www/html/counsyl

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

If I set

```
sudo chown -R admin01:admin01 /var/www/html/counsyl
```

where `admin01` is the username, and this user is not root. I am able to edit the files and folders but the issue is I can't add images or upload plugins etc from the WordPress admin area.

[image]

If I run the following command

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R *
```

It allows me to upload images or plugins etc. But now I am unable to edit the files etc from `admin01` account.

[image]

So what might be the correct permission so that I can edit the files with `admin01` user(not root) and at the same time upload files and folders from the WordPress admin area? I will appreciate if you can give some explanation also so that I understand what I am doing wrong.

Permissions of folders and files inside WordPress folder after running the command

```
sudo chown admin01:www-data -R /var/www/html/counsyl
```

[image]

Comment: Did you also `chmod`? 775 works fine for all my Wordpress installations

Comment: Please give the permission to uploads folder chmod -R 777 DIR

Comment: I have assigned 755 and 644 for folders and files with the find command. Please check the edited question.

Comment: Thanks #Anand. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding both owner as admin01 and user as www-data. This will help you:

```
sudo chown admin01:www-data -R /var/www/html/counsyl
```

Try this, it should work. Structure is like

```
chown -R USERNAME:GROUPNAME /PATH/TO/FILE
```

Thank you

Comment: `sudo chown admin01:www-data -R /var/www/html/counsyl` did not work. It allows admin01 to modify files via FTP but I am still unable to upload images or plugins

Comment: On your upload folder, it should have 0777 permission. Kindly check and if you have not set, apply it. Also check who id the owner of upload folder and let me know

Comment: take screenshot of folder with permission by typing ls -lha if you are using CMD

Comment: Please check the updated question, I have added a screenshot after I run your command `sudo chown admin01:www-data -R /var/www/html/counsyl`

Comment: I think you should fire command to apply 777 permission to wp-content folder. Try sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/counsy/wp-content

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with 755 permission mate?

chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/counsyl

I think above will help you

Comment: I have added `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` I guess that is same as chmod